90s movie where a short ugly midget steals a baby and the mom chases it
I think this movie is from the 1990s. I remember this creature (or something) is a short ugly midget type that comes out of a small statue thing. A Marine husband dies and wife is alone with the baby.
In whole movie the short ugly creature kidnaps the baby and mother chases it for her baby. Meanwhile she meets this nice guy who will help her out to find her baby.
The creature comes out of this small green color bottle statue, they actually found that somewhere or they got it as a gift from someone. In the beginning it tries to come out as that dead Marine husband, but it just resembles him. Later in the morning something it comes back to its natural state and it takes the baby and runs away. In the end it maybe goes back to that small statue.

provide more details if possible

Could be one of the Leprechaun movies, but very vague details

Yes, please provide any detail you can possible remember, stuff like country\language, genre, specific scenes etc. I'm pretty sure I know what you're after and these would really help.

@Walt in the beginning it comes out of this small green color bottle statue, they actually found that somewhere or they got gift from someone, in the beginning it tries to come out as that dead marine husband, just resemble like him and then later in the morning something I don't remember exactly it comes to its natural creation, and it takes the baby and run away, in the end may be it goes back to that small statue may be i don't rem properly

Sounds like Rumpelstiltskin, a 1995 horror version of the famous tale.

In the 1400s, Rumpelstiltskin is imprisoned inside a small jade figurine. In modern-day Los Angeles, the recently widowed wife of a police officer, with baby in tow, finds her way into a witch's shop and purchases a certain figurine, resulting in the cackling beast being freed and demanding possession of the baby.

The widow wishes for another night with her late husband, and it's granted. But in the morning, Rumpelstiltskin appears in his stead and demands her baby. Here's the trailer:




Your right that's the answer I'm looking for, once again thank you Walt, appreciate it
